# Trace the parent AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I need help with tracing the this.parents.name. I tried:

```
trace(this.parent);
trace(this.parent.name);
trace(this.parent());
```

All i get as output is '[object Sprite]' or 'instance1' not the actual name of this parent.

Comment: When it was reported "instance1", that _is_ the name.  The `name` is the instance name of the object. Not sure what else you are expecting to see when you run `this.parent.name`.

Comment: Maybe it would help us to know what you're actually trying to accomplish. What do you plan on doing with the parent's name?

Comment: addChild(cont);
cont.addChild(cont1); 
cont.addChild(cont2);
cont.addChild(cont3);
I need to detect if the object is in cont1,cont2 or cont3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` property refers to the instance name given to the object.  If none is supplied, it will be auto generated to something like **instance1** etc.

You can set the name either in the FlashPro IDE on the properties panel, or through code: `cont.name = "cont";`

I suspect what you do is something like this (though I'm not sure where the code provided lives in terms of scope/context)

```
trace(this.parent == cont); //true if the parent is cont
```

OR

```
switch(this.parent){
    case cont:
        trace("Cont is the parent");
        break;

    case cont1:
        trace("Cont 1 is the parent");
        break;

    case cont2:
        trace("Cont 2 is the parent");
        break;
}
```